Vo se visualizan bien las celdas en google-colaboratory
No visualizo las celdas de código de manera correcta, se ven reducidas, la única manera de visualizarlas de manera completa es si estoy usando pestañas de incognito, me sucede en todos los navegadores, las celdas de texto si se visualizan normales

